# Error on changing "buildToolsVersion" of project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build-tools

I use `Android Studio 3.1.4` and `android gradle plugin version 3.1.4`.

Previously I set `buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"` in `build.gradle` of module and there was no problem in building/running. Today I installed newer version of `build tools` and change `build.gradle` to use that: `buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"`

But when I try to `sync project with gradle files` or `rebuild project` it ends with `AAPT2` error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: \u003citem\u003e inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.","sources":[{"file":"<path to module>/src/main/res/values/ids.xml","position":{"startLine":16,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":752,"endColumn":55,"endOffset":803}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
....
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':<modulee-name>:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

But I do not understand what causes the error. For example addressed line in error is:

```
<item type="id" name="bookmark">false</item>
```

What causes this error and how I can solve this problem?

**Edit**

I added `android.enableAapt2=false` to the `gradle.properties` and it seems ignores error, but causes this warning:

> The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used
>   anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning. It
>   will be removed at the end of 2018..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot assign `false` (nor any other value but it's `name`) to an [ID resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id).

> An ID is a simple resource that is referenced using the value provided in the name attribute (not the name of the XML file). As such, you can combine ID resources with other simple resources in the one XML file, under one  element. Also, remember that an ID resources does not reference an actual resource item; it is simply a unique ID that you can attach to other resources or use as a unique integer in your application.

with `android.enableAapt2=false` it might ignore the logical error, but not "fix it".

Comment: I do not think that using `false` causes the problem; because there is another line in that file:`<item type="id" name="app_rate">false</item>` but error does not point that line.

Comment: @hasanghaforian the problem is that `type="id"` does not permit assigning values. AAPT2 might just ignore the value, where D8 might bug out. and even if it builds - it might not function as expected.

Comment: also the hint, that the `inner element must either be a resource reference or empty` ...is telling about the same; where the "inner element" is the one in between the `> <`.

Comment: I changed that line to `<item type="id" name="bookmark">"foo"</item>`; but error address that line again.

Comment: @hasanghaforian "foo" is a string, not a resource reference. Honestly, just leave it empty: `<item type="id" name="bookmark"/>` as Martin suggested.